# Coercion of a number and a string in comparison operators

Tags: javascript, coercion

I run the following code in a browser console (FireFox and Chromium):

```
console.log('v' > 5);
console.log('v' < 5);
```

Both statements return *false*. It actually comes as no surprise in case of `'v' < 5`, but why does `'v' > 5` return *false*? As far as I understand 5 gets converted to a string that is compared to `'v'` lexicographically. Did I missed something, what coercion rule is applied here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coercion is in the other direction. `'v'` is coerced to number, yielding `NaN`, which will make any comparison with another number return `false`.

See ["What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values) on the behaviour of `NaN`

#### More details

From the EcmaScript specification:

In [12.9.3 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) the evaluation of both `<` and `>` operators is specified, with this important step:

> 6. Let *r* be the result of performing Abstract Relational Comparison *rval < lval* with *LeftFirst* equal to `false`.

And,

> 8. If *r* is `undefined`, return `false`. Otherwise, return *r*.

The [7.2.11 Abstract Relational Comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) starts out with:

> The comparison *x < y*, where *x* and *y* are values, produces `true`, `false`, or `undefined` (which indicates that at least one operand is `NaN`).

NB: Note that `undefined` will lead to a `false` in the final evaluation, as stated in above quoted step 8 of section 12.9.3.

It is then required that after the primitive values have been taken from the operands, and they are not found to be both strings, they should be coerced to Number:

> 5. If both *px* and *py* are Strings, then
>      [...]
> 6. Else
>      a. Let *nx* be *ToNumber(px)*.
>      [...]
>      c. Let *ny* be *ToNumber(py)*.

#### Examples of Evaluated Expressions

Here is a series of comparisons, showing the different outcomes you can get:

```js
function test(value, name) {
   if (arguments.length === 1) name = JSON.stringify(value);
   console.log(name + ' < 11.5 === ' + (value < 11.5) +  
       '. Number(' + name + ') = ', Number(value));
}
test('33');
test('3');
test('+11.9');     // coerces to number 11.9 (sign and decimal)
test('0xA');       // coerces to number 10 (hexadecimal notation)
test('');          // coerces to number 0
test('3v');        // invalid number
test('3e2');       // coerces to number 300 (exponent notation)
test('-Infinity'); // coerces to number -Infinity
test(new Date(), 'new Date()'); // coerces to number of milliseconds 
test({ valueOf: x => 2 }, '{ valueOf: x => 2 }'); // coerces to number 2
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, comparison operators call valueOf() on both sides which would mean comparing 'v' and 5. The problem is greater/less than operators apply strict equality and the differing types means false is returned.

Comment: @BenShelton, try `"3" < 5` (true) , `"7" > 5`  (true), and any variants of that. The relational operators are not strict.

Comment: @BenShelton According to http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-relational-comparison both operands are interpreted as numbers

Comment: @trincot Right you are. Turns out 'valueOf()' is used when comparing an object with a primitive, but strings are converted to numbers in these cases. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: I added some quotations from the EcmaScript specs.

Comment: maybe you add some examples, like stringed numbers become numbers, some text become `NaN` and empty string becomes `0`.

Comment: @NinaScholz, Good idea. I added some examples.